# Retrieving event and htmlInput element from a foreach using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, razor, foreach

I managed to retrieve a dynamic element ID from inside a foreach and send it to a controller this way:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteConfirmed", "Gifts", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-content", id = "formDiv" }))
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.productList)
        {
            <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="DeleteButtonClicked(this)" data-assigned-id="@item.ID" />
        }
    }
```

and here's the relevant script, pointing to the controller's ActionResult method in charge for item deletion:

```
function DeleteButtonClicked(elem) {
        var itemID = $(elem).data('assigned-id');
        if (confirm('sure?')) {
            window.location.href = "/Gifts/DeleteConfirmed/" + itemID; 
}}
```

Now, this works just fine, as itemID is correctly retrieved.
As I would like to add a @Html.AntiForgeryToken() to the form, the idea is to change the MVC controller's Actionmethod into a JsonResult adding a little Ajax to the script, allowing me to pass both itemID and token.

Something like:

```
function DeleteButtonClicked(elem) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var form = $('#formDiv');
   var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();
   var itemID = $(elem).data('assigned-id');
   if (confirm('sure?')) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'json',
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteConfirmed", "Gifts")',
                data: {
                   __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                    id: itemID
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) { window.location.href = "/Gifts/UserProfile?userID=" + data; },
                error: function (data) { window.location.href = '@Url.Action("InternalServerError", "Error")'; }
            });
        }
   dynamic }Some
```

but I have no idea on **how to add the 'event'** to the element (this => elem) in  `<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="DeleteButtonClicked(this)" data-assigned-id="@item.ID" />` that I am using to identify the item inside the foreach loop, in order to pass it to the script.

Above script obviously fails as there's no 'event' (provided this would end to be the only mistake, which I'm not sure at all).

Some help is needed. Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is use jQuery to create an event handler:

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var form = $('#formDiv');
   var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();
   var itemID = $(this).data('assigned-id');
   if (confirm('sure?')) {
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           datatype: 'json',
           url: '@Url.Action("DeleteConfirmed", "Gifts")',
           data: {
              __RequestVerificationToken: token,
               id: itemID
           },
           cache: false,
           success: function (data) { window.location.href = "/Gifts/UserProfile?userID=" + data; },
           error: function (data) { window.location.href = '@Url.Action("InternalServerError", "Error")'; }
       });
   }
});
```

Just make sure you render this script **after** your buttons are rendered. Preferably using the `$(document).onReady` technique.

Comment: Thanks mate, that required a minimum change and worked like a charm. I upvoted your reply but as I still score under 15 of reputation that did not change the post score.As far as I know the $(document).ready() should not be required in this case as 1. the $ at the script start already implies that. 2. You cannot click on something not renderet yet. But I may well be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'on' event handler attachment (http://api.jquery.com/on/). The outer function is shorthand for DOM ready.

```
$(function() {
  $('.some-container').on('click', '.delete-btn', DeleteButtonClicked);
})
```